# JS onclick event in table Collapsibles/Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out how to create onClick event in a table, that works according to the row clicked, displaying hidden siblings.

This table comes from a DB (ajax call)

```
          $("#table-data").append(
            `<tr id="${response.data[i]["id"]}">

            <td id="nameTag${response.data[i]["id"]}"> ${response.data[i]["firstName"] + " " + response.data[i]["lastName"]}</td>
            <td> ${response.data[i]["id"]} </td>
            <td> ${response.data[i]["jobTitle"]} </td>
            <td> ${response.data[i]["email"]} </td>
            <td> ${response.data[i]["department"]} </td>
            <td> ${response.data[i]["location"]} </td>

            </tr>`
```

Here is where I want to get the row on click, but the id should be nameTag[i], where i is the row id.

```
  const nameTag = $("#nameTag1"); //example: if click on row 1 should be this ID.
  const nameTag = $(`#nameTag${response.data[i]["id"]}`); //I tried this way using it inside the ajax call. but it makes open and close row 12 to the infinite... 

  $(document).on("click", nameTag, function () {
    
    $('#nameTag1').siblings().toggle("slow");

  });
```

I tried this for loop but also doesn't work

```
     const table = document.getElementById('table');
     for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
          //do something....
        }
```

If I use fixed ID values for test, like onClick just for nameTag1, opening his siblings, when i click in any row open row 1...

I don't know, but probably I am going to the wrong way, maybe I should use just CSS...

Comment: You want to target the rows, so do just that: `$(document).on('click', '#table-data tr', function () { ... });` Inside the function, you can target the clicked row using `$(this)`, or its cells using `$(this).find('td')`

Comment: It worked, thanks! I just need to figured out how to don't hide the name (because of toggle it's showing all data but it's hiding name).